# Pandas join two DataFrames where one is a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two DataFrames that look like the following:

```
df1:
movieID 1 2 3 4
userID
0       2 0 0 2
1       1 1 4 0
2       0 2 3 0
3       1 2 0 0
```

and

```
df2:
   userID movieID
0       0       2 
1       0       3
2       0       4
3       1       3
```

What I am trying to accomplish is joining the two so that `df2` contains a new column with the associated rating of a user for a specific movie. Thus `df2` in this example would become:

```
df2:
   userID movieID rating
0       0       2      0
1       0       3      0
2       0       4      2
3       1       3      4
```

I don't believe that simply reformatting `df2` to have the same shape as `df1` would work because there is no guarantee that it will have all userIDs or movieIDs, and i've looked into the `merge` function but I'm confused on how to set the `how` and `on` parameters in this scenario. If anyone can explain how could I achieve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) by `row` to index `df1.loc[row.userID, row.movieID]`.

Just make sure the `dtype` of `df1.columns` matches `df2.userID`, and `df2.movieID` matches `df1.index`.

```py
df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(df2.movieID.dtype)
df1.index = df1.index.astype(df2.userID.dtype)

df2['rating'] = df2.apply(lambda row: df1.loc[row.userID, row.movieID], axis=1)

#    userID  movieID  rating
# 0       0        2       0
# 1       0        3       0
# 2       0        4       2
# 3       1        3       4
```